# Codeigniter show comments of deleted users

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The code below helps me to display all the comments (with user info) for particular post.

When a user deactivates his account, I want his comments still be visible for other users but without displaying his info (such as name and city). I want to show default values instead.

So I need to modify my code below so that it will check if user exists or not. If not, return default name and city values.

I am trying to find a solution for several hours but cannot get the result I want. Could you please help me to solve the problem.

```
public function get_comments($post_id){

$this->db->select('comments.comment_text, users.name,users.city');
$this->db->from('comments','users');   
$this->db->where('comments.post_id', $post_id);
$this->db->join('users','comments.user_id = users.user_id');    

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query && $query->num_rows() >= 1){
return $query->result();
}
else {
return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all user information, and after you check if the user is active :

```
$data = $this->db->select('comments.comment_text, users.name, users.city, users.active');
->from('comments');
->where('comments.post_id', $post_id);
->join('users','comments.user_id = users.user_id')
->get()result();
```

And then in your view you check if your user is active, if this is the case you will display all the information, if you display only what you want :

```
foreach($data as $d) 
{
  if($d->active == 1) // User active
  {
    echo .....;
  }
  else // User not active
  {
    echo ...;
  }
}
```